# keep the submitted values for dropdown and radio button

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which has First Name, Last Name text boxes, Radio button(Yes or No) and Dropdown list box. I submit the page to itself to insert the data in the database. I would like to retain the values after reloading the page. How can this be done?

```
 <form name="Form" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
```

I appreciate any help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply echo their values in your inputs...

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $_POST['fname'] ?>">
...
<input type="radio" name="r1" value="v1" <?php if($_POST['r1'] == 'v1') echo 'checked' ?>>
...
```

Comment: You should be filtering those values to prevent XSS attacks of course :]

Comment: How to prevent XSS attacks? What is the filter for database? I am new to PHP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS and `mysql_real_esace_string` function for SQL injection.
 Take a look at [these article](http://www.addedbytes.com/writing-secure-php/)

Comment: Thanks for the article. How do I retain the value for dropdown?

Comment: just like radio button : `<select name="s1"><option value="v1" <?php if($_POST['s1'] == 'v1') echo selected ?>>Volvo</option>`

Comment: Dropdown list populates from the database.      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {       echo "<option value=\"".$row['state_id']."\">".$row["state_code"]."</option>";        
     }